# Link libraries that depend on each other from project CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I have quite a pickle with CMake that I wasn't able to solve following common advice here on StackOverflow. I have the following project:

```
# SDL2
add_subdirectory(vendor/SDL2-2.0.16)
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL2-2.0.16/include")
set(SDL2_LIBRARY "SDL2")
set(SDL2_LIBDIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL2-2.0.16")

# ogg
add_subdirectory(vendor/libogg-1.3.5)
set(OGG_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/libogg-1.3.5/include")
set(OGG_LIBRARY "ogg")

# vorbis
add_subdirectory(vendor/libvorbis-1.3.7)
set(OGG_VORBIS_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/libvorbis-1.3.7/include")
set(OGG_VORBIS_LIBRARY "vorbis")

# SDL2 Mixer
add_subdirectory(vendor/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4)
set(SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4")
set(SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY "SDL_mixer")

add_executable(myProject ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(myProject PRIVATE ${MY_PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS} PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myProject PUBLIC ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY})
```

The idea is to provide all of the dependencies necessary to build SDL2 and SDL2_mixer. So far, that means ogg and vorbis. I have created a very simplistic CMakeLists.txt for ogg:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(libogg)

configure_file(include/ogg/config_types.h.in include/ogg/config_types.h @ONLY)

set(OGG_HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/ogg/config_types.h
    include/ogg/ogg.h
    include/ogg/os_types.h
)

set(OGG_SOURCES
    src/bitwise.c
    src/framing.c
    src/crctable.h
)

if(WIN32 AND BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    list(APPEND OGG_SOURCES win32/ogg.def)
endif()

add_library(ogg ${OGG_HEADERS} ${OGG_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(ogg PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)
```

And a similar one for vorbis. The one for SDL_mixer is also simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(SDL_mixer VERSION 2.0.4)
set(ENABLE_DEFS "MUSIC_OGG")

set(SRC_C_FILES bla bla bla)
set(SRC_H_FILES bla bla bla)

add_library(SDL_mixer ${SRC_C_FILES} ${SRC_H_FILES})
target_link_libraries(SDL_mixer PUBLIC ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${OGG_LIBRARY} ${OGG_VORBIS_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(SDL_mixer PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OGG_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OGG_VORBIS_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_compile_definitions(SDL_mixer PUBLIC "${ENABLE_DEFS}")
```

But, unfortunately, I'm still not able to link. Curiously, on my project, my sources can see ogg. But SDL_mixer cannot:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/bin/c++ -rdynamic MY_SOURCES -o ../bin/myProject  -Wl,-rpath:/var/dev/qube/build/vendor/SDL2-2.0.16 vendor/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/libSDL_mixer.a -lrt vendor/SDL2-2.0.16/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.16.0 vendor/libvorbis-1.3.7/libvorbis.a vendor/libogg-1.3.5/libogg.a -lm
/bin/ld: vendor/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/libSDL_mixer.a(music_ogg.c.o): in function `OGG_Load':
music_ogg.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `ov_clear'
```

- Do I have to add ogg and vorbis as `add_subdirectory()` inside the SDL_mixer project?
- Is it not possible to statically link with those libraries?

Comment: You are creating Ogg library from 3 files. Are you sure that `ov_clear` is defined in one of these files?

Comment: `ov_clear` is defined in `libvorbis-1.3.7/lib/vorbisfile.c`, which is included in libvorbis.

Comment: It seems that `vorbisfile.c` is [compiled into](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/master/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L79) `vorbisfile` library, not into `vorbis` one. So you need to link with `vorbisfile`.

Comment: Can you try adding libvorbis.a before libSDL_mixer.a?

Answer (score 0):

> But, unfortunately, I'm still not able to link. Curiously, on my
> project, my sources can see ogg. But SDL_mixer cannot:

The only reason I could see why ogg could see your sources and SDL_mixer can't is due to the order of libraries in your link command.

```
 vendor/libvorbis-1.3.7/libvorbis.a vendor/libogg-1.3.5/libogg.a
```

By the time of linking ogg objects, vorbis symbols are already included in symbols table.

Try this:

```
target_link_libraries(SDL_mixer PUBLIC  ${OGG_VORBIS_LIBRARY} ${OGG_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```